# некорректно работает binding android kotlin

Tags: android, binding, kotlin, android-data-binding

Привет всем! Честно говоря я уже устал пытаться решить эту проблему - все проверил двадцать раз. Приложение компилируется, все ок, но вот данные с формы не обновляются! Допустим я ввожу статические данные в xml. Затем пользователь их меняет, и я хочу взять свежие данные, но у меня всегда возвращается лишь то, что я положил туда в начале. Я пробовал кидать данные через класс (в официальном примере), но это не помогло. Искал ошибку в связке gradl-ов, но и там ничего сверх-естественного не нашлось.Ниже привожу листинги всех основных моментов, вы уж извините за кол-во листингов. Если вы не можете помочь с проблемой, плжлста дайте пример 100% рабочего примера, со всеми gradle.

---

**Gradle-project**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3-2'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta7'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Gradle-app**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.darkt.makeyouself"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

//    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'

    def firebaseLibVersion = '11.2.0'
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$firebaseLibVersion"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:$firebaseLibVersion"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:$firebaseLibVersion"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:$firebaseLibVersion"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$firebaseLibVersion"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:$firebaseLibVersion"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$firebaseLibVersion"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:$firebaseLibVersion"

    compile 'com.kelvinapps:rxfirebase:0.0.15'

    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.0'
    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.0.0-beta7"

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**FBLogin** - activity на которой и происходит все дело. Привожу урезанный вариант, основные моменты:

```
class FBLogin : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var binding: ActivityFbloginBinding? = null
    private var auth: FirebaseAuth? = null
    private var dbHelper: FirebaseHelper? =null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_fblogin)
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        dbHelper = FirebaseHelper()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fblogin)

       // binding?.executePendingBindings()

        loginButton.setOnClickListener{_ -> loginToSystem()}

    }

    private fun loginToSystem() {
        binding?.executePendingBindings()
        //showProgressDialog()
        val email = binding?.userName?.text.toString().trim()
        val password = binding?.userPass?.text.toString()
        //binding?.executePendingBindings()

        Toast.makeText(this, email, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        Toast.makeText(this, password, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()


    }
}
```

И собственно **fblogin_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
    </data>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/grey_main"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:context="com.example.darkt.makeyouself.activities.FBLogin"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/userName"
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="43dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="test01"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="Login"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/userPass"
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:text="123456"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/userName"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="74dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="245dp"
            tools:text="Password"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/loginButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textColor="@color/green_main"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/userPass"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/userPass" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

---

Код приведен совсем в простом варианте. Как уже говорил, я пробовал все подряд, и вроде как я все делаю по-примерам с оф.сайт и просто с форумов, но вот переменные никак с формой связь не поддерживают. (текущий пример взять с java я использовал подобные конструкции и все работало!). Прошу не судить строго за код и минусами меня не забрасывать, это первой приложение на kotlin.

Comment: Т. е. что бы пользователь не написал в поля имени и пароля, при клике всегда выводятся тосты с `test01` и `123456`?

Comment: так точно! Товарищ помог исправить! Нужно удалить лишнюю строку (моя ошибка) setContentView(R.layout.activity_fblogin) и все заработает корректно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне кажется, вот это лишнее в `onCreate()`

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_fblogin)
```

Вы пересоздаете снова UI, уже без байндинга.

Comment: вы оказались правы! Я второй раз использую binding, и по неопытности продублировал строчку кода =( Спасибо вам большое!! Репутацию к сожалению поднять пока не могу, я недавно зарегестрировался тут. Но как смогу, вернусь и подниму =)

Comment: Рад был помочь!

Comment: @ГеоргийЧеботарев поднял репутацию?

Comment: @Elena_Gnil конечно, человек же мне помог найти ошибку